# emacs key binding "C-:" for avy-goto-char failed

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

add a key-binding in emacs init file:
`(global-set-key (kbd "C-:") 'avy-goto-char)`
for avy-goto-char function.

When I press down **Ctrl** and **:(with Shift pressed)**, nothing happens.
But when use **Meta-x avy-goto-char**, the commands list window shows **C-:** already bound to this function. And this function works well.

And if I replace char **:** to **j** (for example), it works fine.
Anyone met this problem before. Please help

Comment: You're probably using Emacs in a terminal which is incapable of sending Emacs a `C-:`

Comment: Yes it is terminal. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome.  That also means this is a duplicate, so I've closed it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just like **phils** said, it is used in a terminal